# Manuals of Style and Typography for British and American English

Tags: american-english, british-english, typography, style-manuals

I would like to know which manuals of **style** and **typography** are the most common ones for British and American English. I am interested in the basic manuals and the manuals for technical scientists (physicists, chemists, mathematicians, programmers and engineers).

I would be very much obliged if you can recommend me any manuals, both books and websites.

Answer (score 0):

1. This [link](http://calstatela.libguides.com/style) may help you:

   In particular, it lists style manuals to use for *Anthropology,
   Business, Education, Psychology, and other Social Sciences,
   Sociology, Literature, History,Physical, Natural, and Social
   Sciences, Science, and the Humanities*.
2. Likewise, [this link](https://hsl.lib.umn.edu/biomed/help/stylemanuals) which lists writing style guides for medical sciences and technical persons.
3. **Handbook of Typography for the Mathematical Sciences**
   by Steven G. Krantz

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.